# How is chi squared test used in this paper?

Tags: chi-squared-test

[image]
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RCCoPbA6QTSyO_v-nmjCz5f7iV6V60kM/view?usp=sharing

Kristiansen, S., & Severin, M. C. (2020). Loot box engagement and problem gambling among adolescent gamers: Findings from a national survey. Addictive Behaviors, 103, 106254.

I have been trying to understand how chi-squared test is used in these tables to show association. I am at a absolute loss. I learnt some basic chi-square tests like test of independence and goodness of fit test. But for goodness of fit test, you would need a distribution to model the expectation, which I cannot find in the paper. I need help to understand how they calculate the chi-square and p-values.

Comment: Can you please post the full citation for the paper (not just a link)?

Comment: I would try this: get expected column proportions from column totals. Then apply those to each row in a separate test. If so, that's not a procedure that I would recommend. A better procedure is an overall chi-square test followed by some inspection of residuals, (observed $-$ expected) / root of expected.